# why doesn't this work? it's a simple console log inside a loop

Tags: javascript, string

```js
var line = "Stands so high   ";

let position = -1;
for (; line[position] == " ";) {
  position--;
  console.log(position);
}
```

the output gives nothing. why is it this way? I want it to console.log the value **position**. I have used both **node** and the **chrome developer tools** console. Doesn't work on either one.

Comment: Your check condition isn’t met, so the loop doesn’t run

Comment: array indexes are non-negative.

Comment: Did you mean to start position at `line.length`?  your `for` loop maybe could/should be written `let position; for (position=line.length; line[position] == ' ' || position >= 0; position--) { ... }`

Comment: `line[-1]==" "` is `false` so the loop doesn't do any iterations.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as your question is not clear enough, I hope I can shed light to the use of for...loop.

for...loop is used for iteration. To traverse(pass-through) a sequence(such as string) or collections(such as arrays), which are subscriptable(i.e use index numbers).
To be able to use for...loop syntax, you need to provide 3-parts in the for...loop declaration part. **initialization**, **test_expression** and **step**. Although, their use IS NOT RESTRICTED to within the pair of parenthesis. That is why your piece of code can be used just needs a little restructuring. In fact, they can be omitted entirely to form an **infinite loop**. See syntax below:

```
for (initialization ; test_expression ; step/incrementation_or_decrementation){ ... }


for (; ; ){ ... } // Omitting the 3-parts turns this for...loop into an infinite loop.
```

Before the body of the loop (denoted by **...** above) can be executed, your **test_expression** MUST evaluate to **true**. Your **initialization** and **step** are ensuring that at a point, that **test_expression** is evaluated to **false**, so that your for...loop does not enter into an infinite loop.

Let's look closer at our Code[Follow my comment]:

```
var line="Stands so high   ";
let position=-1;  // This line serves your **initialization** part below.
for(;line[position]==" ";) {  // Your **test_expression** IS NOT evaluating to **true**
    position--;   // This line serves your **step** part above.
    console.log(position);
}
```

**NOTE:**
In Javascript, **it's not possible to provide a negative index** like you did in your for...loop declaration. This is 100% possible with Python but not JS. That's why your **test_expression** IS NOT evaluating to **true**.

```
line[position]  // will always evaluates to **undefined** because position is **-1** for the 1st expected iteration.
```

...and **undefined** IS NOT EQUALS TO **" "**.

**SOLUTION 1:**
Consider restructuring your code as follows if you want to log **position** in the iteration up to the first occurrence of white-space:

```
var line="Stands so high   ";

let position=-1; // Your **initialization** suggest you're traversing from letter **S** to the right side.
for(;line[position]!=" ";) { // Consider changing **==** to **!=**
    position++; // Consider **step to increment** i.e move to next character to test it.
    console.log(position);
}
```

...if this is your intention, you can simply achieve this by quickly locating your first white-space.

```
var line="Stands so high   ";
console.log( line.indexOf(" ") ); // This will log 6, which is the position of first white-space.
```

**SOLUTION 2:**
If your intention is to count the number of words in your variable **line**, use the following:

```
var line="Stands so high   ";
console.log( line.trim().replace("  ", " ").split(" ").length ); // This will output **3**, meaning 3-words.
```

...here, I have chained several methods to each other to feed the output of one method to the input of another.
**line.trim()** removes the leading and trailing white-spaces(i.e spaces before and after the real sentence)
**.replace("  ", " ")** replace all occurrence of double white-spaces with single white-space.
**.split(" ")**  breaks the sentence into an array of words using the single white-space as delimiter. since white-spaces are used as separator of words.
**.length** counts the total words in the array.

Feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: "you need to provide 3-parts in the for...loop", you don't.

Answer (score 2):

While in some other languages, negative string indexes can be used to count from the end backwards, this is not the case in JavaScript.

Newer JS engines support the `at` method for that:

```js
var line="Stands so high   ";

let position=-1;
for(;line.at(position)==" ";) {
    position--;
    console.log(position);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var line = "Stands so high";

for (let position = 0; position < line.length; position++) {
  console.log(position);
}
```